# Does this function compute the natural logarithm of a number with an exact precision of 3 digits?

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point, logarithm

I have the following algorithm in my textbook that should compute the natural log of a number with an exact precision of 3 digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double logN(double a, double li, double ls)
{
    if(a == 1)
        return 0;
    else if(fabs(li - ls) < 0.0001)

        return (li + ls) / 2;
    else if((exp(li) - a) * (exp((li + ls) / 2) - a) < 0)
        return logN(a, li, (li + ls) / 2);
    else
        return logN(a, (li + ls) / 2, ls);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << logN(3, 0, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << logN(4, 0, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << logN(5, 0, 5) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This statement looks wrong to me:

```
else if(fabs(li - ls) < 0.0001)
```

For example, if I have 2 numbers: `0.9992` and `0.9996`. Both numbers have the first 3 digits equal, but the difference between them is `0.0004` which is greater than `0.0001` and thus the test will fail. What am I missing?

Comment: What do the parameters `a`, `li`, and `ls` mean?

Comment: Precision of x digits doesn't necessarily mean having the first x digits in common. For example 0.999999999 is within 3 digits of precision of 1.000000, but the first 3 digits are not in common

Comment: @NayukiMinase `a` is the number whose log I am computing and `li` and `ls` are the boundaries over the interval (0, a) where the solution is. I know,  the code is not self descriptive, but I didn't want to alter the original source code from the textbook. By the way, this is bisection method, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is needed in order `(li + ls) / 2` to work correctly.

For example:

```
0.999 - 0.9981 = 0.0009 < 0.001
```

but:

```
(0.999 + 0.9981) / 2 = 0.99855
```

On the other hand:

```
(0.9999 + 0.9998) / 2 = 0.99985
```

which rounds up to 1, when rounding to 3rd digit.